# Correcting DB2 stored procedure error

Tags: database, stored-procedures, db2

I am creating a stored procedure inside my DB2 database, here is my stored procedure codes:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PWDCHANGE (UNAME IN VARCHAR(32), 
                                           OLDPWD IN VARCHAR(32), 
                                           NEWPWD IN VARCHAR(32)) 
    AS
    BEGIN
      IF LOGINTABLE.USERNAME = UNAME AND LOGINTABLE.PASSWORD = OLDPWD THEN
      UPDATE LOGINTABLE SET PASSWORD = NEWPWD;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Password Changed Successfully!');
      ELSE DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Incorrect Old Password Input');
    END IF;
    END;
```

But as I deploy it in my IBM Data Studio it displays an error which says:

```
    Deploy SENJOBLADE.PWDCHANGE(VARCHAR(32), VARCHAR(32), VARCHAR(32))

    Running
    SENJOBLADE.PWDCHANGE - Deploy started.
    Create stored procedure returns SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601.
    SENJOBLADE.PWDCHANGE: 1: An unexpected token "VARCHAR" was found following "PWDCHANGE (UNAME IN".  Expected tokens may include:  ",".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.13.111
    An unexpected token "VARCHAR" was found following "PWDCHANGE (UNAME IN".  Expected tokens may include:  ",".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.13.111
    SENJOBLADE.PWDCHANGE - Deploy failed.
    SENJOBLADE.PWDCHANGE - Roll back completed successfully.
```

I don't know why VARCHAR is an unexpected token, I don't know what to change to be able to deploy my stored procedure. The function of this stored procedure is to accept 3 inputs which is used for password changing, a username, a current password, and the replacement password that's why I have 3 IN values.

SENJOBLADE is my schema name, LOGINTABLE is the table name which has two columns, the USERNAME & PASSWORD column

I tried removing the VARCHARs and this error displays:

```
    Deploy SENJOBLADE.PWDCHANGE(IN, IN, IN)

    Running
    SENJOBLADE.PWDCHANGE - Deploy started.
    Create stored procedure returns SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601.
    SENJOBLADE.PWDCHANGE: 2: An unexpected token "BEGIN" was found following "PWD IN) 
            AS
    ".  Expected tokens may include:  ":".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.13.111

    An unexpected token "BEGIN" was found following "PWD IN) 
            AS
    ".  Expected tokens may include:  ":".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.13.111

    SENJOBLADE.PWDCHANGE - Deploy failed.
    SENJOBLADE.PWDCHANGE - Roll back completed successfully.
```

Please help, I'm still learning about stored procedures so I'm not yet used to it. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `Deploy SENJOBLADE.PWDCHANGE(UNAME, OLDPWD, NEWPWD)`

Comment: how can I do that? I deploy my stored procs in IBM Data Studio by right-clicking and selecting DEPLOY

Comment: Sorry, my answer won't help, but this should - remove the word `as` and replace it with the phrase `LANGUAGE SQL`, as follows:
 
    `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PWDCHANGE (UNAME IN VARCHAR(32), 
                                           OLDPWD IN VARCHAR(32), 
                                           NEWPWD IN VARCHAR(32)) 
    LANGUAGE SQL
    BEGIN
    ...`